# How to load my properties file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties, websphere, message

I'm using websphere and Java EE and get this error message:

```
Exception reading propertiesfile in init java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java(Compiled Code))
    at se.prv.register.admin.util.MessageHandler.loadDictionary(MessageHandler.java:90)
    at se.prv.register.admin.util.MessageHandler.<clinit>(MessageHandler.java:15)
```

This is my code

```
package se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.util;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MessageHandler extends AbstractTextHandler{
    private static Properties dictionary;
    private final static String dictionaryFileName="messages.properties";
    private final static String className="se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.util.MessageHandler";
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MessageHandler.class);

    static {
        loadDictionary();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = getParameterizedMessageTest("TEST",new String[]{"PETER","GÖRAN"});
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    public static String getMessage(String key){
        return getMessage(key,true);
    }
    public static String getMessage(String key,boolean useReference){
        logger.debug("!!!! getMessage "+ key);
        if (key==null || key.length()==0){
            throw new RuntimeException("GetMessage without key");
        }
        if (dictionary==null){
            loadDictionary();
        }
        if (useReference){
            return getFullMessage(getMessage(dictionary,key));
        }
        else {
            //String str = getMessage(dictionary,key);
            //logger.debug(str);
            String str2 = getCoreMessage(getMessage(dictionary,key));
            //logger.debug(str2);
            return str2;
        }
    }
    public static String getFirstPartOfMessage(String key){
        if (key==null || key.length()==0){
            throw new RuntimeException("GetMessage without key");
        }
        if (dictionary==null){
            loadDictionary();
        }
        String msg = getMessage(dictionary,key);
        int pos = msg.indexOf('$');
        if (pos==-1){
            return msg;
        }
        else {
            return msg.substring(0,pos);
        }
    }
    public static String getLastPartOfMessage(String key){
        if (key==null || key.length()==0){
            throw new RuntimeException("GetMessage without key");
        }
        if (dictionary==null){
            loadDictionary();
        }
        String msg = getMessage(dictionary,key);
        int pos = msg.lastIndexOf('$');
        if (pos==-1){
            return msg;
        }
        else {
            return msg.substring(pos+1);
        }
    }
    public static String getParameterizedMessage(String key, String [] params){
        if (dictionary==null){
            loadDictionary();
        }
        return getParameterizedMessage(dictionary,key,params);
    }
    private static void loadDictionary(){       
        String fileName = getPropertiesPath()+dictionaryFileName;
        //String fileName = "se/prv/register/admin/dao/sql-map-config.xml";

        try {
            dictionary=new Properties();
            //InputStream fileInput =  Class.forName("se.prv.register.admin.util.MessageHandler").getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            InputStream fileInput =  Class.forName(className).getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            dictionary.load(fileInput);
            fileInput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception reading propertiesfile in init "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            dictionary=null;
        }
    }
    private static String getCoreMessage(String str){
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        boolean doCopy=true;
        for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            if (str.charAt(i)=='$'){
                doCopy=!doCopy;
                continue;
            }
            if (doCopy){
                buff.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }
    private static String getFullMessage(String str){
        int pos = str.indexOf('$');
        if (pos==-1){
            return str;
        }
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(str);

        int originalLength = buff.length();
        for (int i=pos+1;i<buff.length();i++){
            if (buff.charAt(i)== '$'){
                String key = buff.substring(pos+1,i).trim();
                String msg = getMessage(dictionary,key);
                buff.replace(pos,i+1,msg);
                if (buff.length()!=originalLength){
                    i += (buff.length()-originalLength);
                    originalLength=buff.length();
                }
                pos = buff.indexOf("$",i+1);
                if (pos==-1){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    i = pos+1;
                }
            }
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }
//  private static void loadDictionary(){       
//      loadDictionary(dictionary,dictionaryFileName,className);
//  }
}

package se.prv.register.admin.util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import se.prv.framework.general.PRVWebSphere;
import se.prv.framework.util.Strings;

public abstract class AbstractTextHandler {

        private static final String propertiesPath="//se//prv//register//properties//";
        protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractTextHandler.class);

//      static {
//          loadProperties();
//      }
        protected static String getPropertiesPath(){
            return propertiesPath;
        }
        protected static String getMessage(Properties dictionary,String key){
            if (dictionary==null){
                return "ERROR";
            }
            String msg = dictionary.getProperty(key);
            //System.out.println("KEY="+key);
            if (msg==null){
                return "?!Meddelande " +key + " saknas!?";
            }
            return msg;
        }
        protected static String getParameterizedMessage(Properties dictionary,String key,String []params){
            if (dictionary==null){
                return "ERROR";
            }
            String msg = dictionary.getProperty(key);
            if (msg==null){
                return "?!Meddelande " +key + " saknas!?";
            }
            if (params==null){
                return msg;
            }
            StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(msg);
            for (int i=0;i<params.length;i++){
                String placeHolder = "<<"+(i+1)+">>";
                if (buff.indexOf(placeHolder)!=-1){
                    replace(buff,placeHolder,params[i]);
                }
                else {
                    remove(buff,placeHolder);
                }
            }
            return buff.toString();
        }
        public static String getParameterizedMessageTest(String key,String []params){
            String msg = "HEJ <<1>>!HUR MÅR DU? HEJ DÅ FRÅN <<2>>";
            if (msg==null){
                return "?!Meddelande saknas!?";
            }
            if (params==null){
                return msg;
            }
            StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(msg);
            for (int i=0;i<params.length;i++){
                String placeHolder = "<<"+(i+1)+">>";
                if (buff.indexOf(placeHolder)!=-1){
                    replace(buff,placeHolder,params[i]);
                }
                else {
                    remove(buff,placeHolder);
                }
            }
            return buff.toString();
        }
        private static void replace(StringBuffer buff,String placeHolder,String param){
            int pos = buff.indexOf(placeHolder);
            if (pos==-1){
                return;
            }
            buff.replace(pos,pos+placeHolder.length(),param);
        }
        private static void remove(StringBuffer buff,String placeHolder){
            int pos = buff.indexOf(placeHolder);
            if (pos==-1){
                return;
            }
            buff.replace(pos,pos+placeHolder.length(),placeHolder);
        }
        protected static void loadDictionary(Properties dictionary,String fileName,String className){       
            //String fileName = "se/prv/register/admin/dao/sql-map-config.xml";

            try {
                dictionary=new Properties();
                InputStream fileInput =  Class.forName("se.prv.register.admin.util.AbstractTextHandler").getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
                dictionary.load(fileInput);
                fileInput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                logger.error("Exception reading propertiesfile in init "+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                dictionary=null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've put my messages file messages.properties in the same directory as the log4j.properties file so I think it should get picked up. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you are seeing is a null pointer exception thrown from the depth of `Properties.load()`.  The reason is that the passed parameter (`fileInput`) is null.  Most likely because the path specified in `fileName` is incorrect.

Try prepending the path with `/`.

Also, make sure the file exists.  The `getResourceAsStream()` method will look for the file in the resources associated with the class (e.g. it has to be part of the .jar if you run your program from one).

Comment: I run the program from inside IBM RAd which is based on Eclipse. I try load the properties file from disk but it still gives me an exception even when inspecting that the filename points to the real file.

Comment: If you are trying to load the file from disk, you need to use `dictionary.load`, passing a Reader (e.g. FileReader) to it.  The `getResourceAsStream()` method looks for the path in the resources.  Have you tried prepending the path with `/`?  Your cited code in the question has a comment that gives me the impression that the path does not start with `/`.  In this case the path is interpreted as relative to the class's location [cont.]

Comment: [cont] e.g. if the class resides in the folder "se/prv/register/admin/dao/" and you specify the resource path as "se/prv/register/admin/dao/sql-map-config.xml", the class loader will be looking for a file at "se/prv/register/admin/dao/se/prv/register/admin/dao/sql-map-config.xml" (Note the douplication of the directory hierarchy.);  if you specify the path as "/se/prv/register/admin/dao/sql-map-config.xml", the loader will be looking for a file at "se/prv/register/admin/dao/sql-map-config.xml"

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could load the properties files placing it in the same directory as the class file and that is good for now.

Answer (score 2):

You should load the properties file as a classpath resources rather than a File from file system. Read this article on how to do that [Smartly load your properties](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html).

Comment: Yes I think I should use ResourceBundle but this code was developed outside of my development and taken from another project, said that we should use properties like this project does. So I'm free to change it as long as I make the file usable and I'm cosidering changing the use to using a ResourceBundle but I'm skeptical that in the example Enumeration is used and it iterates to load the proeprties which semms like it is not the best level of abstraction. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the below,

```
InputStream fileInput = Class.forName(className).getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

do this:

```
InputStream fileInput = MessageHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks but it still gives me an exception when trying to load the properties file.

Comment: Your `propertiesPath` is wrong. Change it to `se/prv/register/properties` and see if it works. Is it where the `log4j.properties` is present too?

Comment: Testing setting propertiesPath to empty and using just the filename and placing the properties file in the same directory as the class works. I just wanted to place the properties file in a more convenient location, same directory as the log4j properties file which might not get picked up since I'm running this file standalone and not on the WAS server (I'm using the main method of the class to test it.)

Answer (score 1):

The line 
`InputStream fileInput =  Class.forName(className).getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);`

returns `null`.

This is the reason that NPE is thrown into reader.

The question is why input stream is null? Because `fileName` contains wrong value. So, debug it. Toggle break point in line

`String fileName = getPropertiesPath()+dictionaryFileName;`

and see what does it return.

Comment: I debugged the fileName and it seems OK to me: `filename://se//prv//register//properties//messages.properties` That file exists.